# Downloading embedded video using python(like:fembed)

Tags: python, video, download

I am trying to download an embedded link via python, below is a sample link

https://www.fembed.com/v/e2zklh-5klepn8k

I use request or selenium to find the downloading link

like this:https://fvs.io/redirector?token=ZWVWc3kxNlJ0SmFjck9WQUFIUUNGRzNrUjFjK0pKV2ZSTngyTmZEOWZieVFERy9lZmEwVXBWamcrRlE4eFJ5ZTF6VGNyTXVKTy85WDQ2Y3Q5cnkyczFpUGIvN004cUVoSE5HM2lJWDQwZkQ3cEdYSDh2UWxYbmtjanN1WlhtTTZSbHQydk9ZUmQzUmRMazdnMVFQNVVuQzU2YUVkZ08vSzpoSmxVUlVlbzNibUd3bTIxSzNrNTlRPT0

I have been looking all over and I see how to download this videos using python.

do any of you have any ideas? let me know if you need more info and as always thank you for your time.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will notice that under `Inspect Element > Network`, the only media file that browser picks up is a `.mp4` file, which is the video's file.

[image]

[Here](https://www1469.hlsmp4.com/token=lxQexSt45Sb18F46Mfyu_Q/1572893426/173.232.0.0/49/0/45/ca36aa126d844815b92837ab223b6450-480p.mp4) is the video URL that it gives me. It does have a `token=` parameter, so it might not work in your machine unless you go to the original page and do the steps above.

Knowing the knowledagble above, you should be able to use Selenium (or another tool) to keep track of the incoming network traffic once you accessed the original URL and extract the only traffic with the `.mp4` ending. From there, a simple download with `requests` or `aiohttp` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I know you say that You will notice that under Inspect Element > Network, the only media file that browser picks up is a .mp4 file, which is the video's file.But,how can i find this video links ""by python""?This is a very important step. do any of you have any ideas?

Comment: You could use something like [`selenium-wire`](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire), or do some research with "capture network data selenium python".

Answer (score 1):

First, play the video and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Touch the player and you will get something like this:

```
<video class="jw-video jw-reset" tabindex="-1" disableremoteplayback="" webkit-playsinline="" playsinline="" preload="auto" src="https://fvs.io/redirector?token=L3dENkNhZnhqODFHbDVUYmkzb3lyK0tvanhlWm5mNFZEb3lEZXJHeFZMQ0hWUU43MWhjUEhaMS9KKzlhbzh0T1J5MnJmRWx5N1Y5ekl5VmZPY2tFblhmYkVHOWtLTnlVUk1xQUNhcmJma0p5N3FyWDhPdzlaeXNhSlNJRFUrT1dpbCszajhNUnBpb3hXcjNqQjduNGd0UEI3WDg0NUZMWDpraWZoU2JUMVdaQWdubzRRbnc0SlhnPT0"></video>
```

Now, you will have to copy what is inside the `src=`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send a post request to 
https://gcloud.live/api/source/*id*
e.g
https://gcloud.live/api/source/e2zklh-5klepn8k. The returned json data will contain the link. [Code example](https://github.com/vn-ki/anime-downloader/blob/master/anime_downloader/extractors/gcloud.py)

Fembed and gcloud uses the same ID system and returns the same links from my testing so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Send a post requests to https://femax20.com/api/source/your_file_id. You will get the response with the direct url to the file.
I am doing the same and I hope its not illegal.

Answer (score 0):

After you get URL as mentioned here from other people, try this function to download the viedeo.

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(video_url, download_path)
```